# O que há de errado?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class desafio {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char op;
        float soma;
        float mult;
        float sub;
        float div;
        float num;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        op = entrada.next().charAt(0);

            switch (op) {
                case '+': while (num = entrada.nextFloat() != 0) {
                    soma += num;
                }
                    break;

                case '-': while (num = entrada.nextFloat() != 0) {
                    sub = entrada;
                    sub -= num;
                }
                    break;
                case 'x': while(num = entrada.nextFloat() != 0) {
                    mult = 1;
                    mult *= num;
                }
                case '/': while(num = entrada.nextFloat() != 0) {
                    div = 1;
                    num = entrada;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Está dividindo certo?

Comment: div = 1?; tá certo disto?

Comment: Na verdade eu enviei antes de alterar a última operação entretanto aparecem alguns erros estranhos. 
(Estou iniciando em java).

"incompatible types".

Comment: Primeiro você precisa dizer o que você quer fazer.
Mesmo assim: você não inicializou a variável soma antes de usá-la, em soma += num.
Na sua divisão você está apenas fazendo: num = entrada. Talvez nao seja isso que você queira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você declara `num = entrada.nextFloat() != 0` dessa forma você acaba atribuindo um valor do tipo `boolean` para `num`, isso porque a expressão dessa forma retorna se o número digitado é ou não igual a zero, ou seja, um `true` ou `false`. Como você declarou previamente que num é um `float` você recebe o erro de tipos imcompatíveis.

Com uma simples modificada seu código funciona:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Desafio {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char op;
        float result = 0;
        float num;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        op = entrada.next().charAt(0);

        switch (op) {
            case '+':
                System.out.println("Você escolheu soma!");
                do {
                    System.out.println("Digite um número para somar: (Digite 0 para sair)");
                    num = entrada.nextFloat();
                    result += num;
                } while (num != 0);
                break;

            case '-':
                System.out.println("Você escolheu subtração!");
                do {
                    System.out.println("Digite um número para subtrair: (Digite 0 para sair)");
                    num = entrada.nextFloat();
                    result -= num;
                } while (num != 0);
                break;

            case 'x':
                System.out.println("Você escolheu multiplicação!");
                do {
                    System.out.println("Digite um número para multiplicar: (Digite 0 para sair)");
                    num = entrada.nextFloat();
                    result *= num;
                } while (num != 0);
                break;

            case '/':
                System.out.println("Você escolheu divisão!");
                do {
                    System.out.println("Digite um número para dividir: (Digite 0 para sair)");
                    num = entrada.nextFloat();
                    result /= num;
                } while (num != 0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Nenhuma operação matemática escolhida.");
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Duas observações: Coloque sempre o default no switch case para tratar se nenhuma condição for atendida e lembre-se que nome de classe sempre com a primeira letra maiúscula ;)

De resto é isso, bons estudos!

Comment: Bruno, muito obrigado pela ajuda, conseguiu esclarecer essa dúvida que eu tinha do erro gerado. 
Valeu pelas dicas, prestarei mais atenção!

Comment: @LucasAranha se essa resposta solucionou como problema, marque-a como solução. É o "check" que aparece debaixo do número de votos.